# Steam two install locations

Tags: steam

I have two install locations of steam games... 
`~/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/` and `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/` 
Not sure why, but I'd like to know why this is? My other computer just has the first one.

Comment: I only have the 2nd one. What are the dates on the files in the folders? Maybe one folder is old.

Comment: They are linked folders most likely, I wrote the answer on my own question. ALso just now, I typed `ll` and it says `steam -> debian-installation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so when I did the `l` command, steam is `steam@` and the other one was `debian-installation/` After looking into it the @ after the directory means symbolic link, so it seems that they are the same but just linked directories.